# How to pass value to a variable defined in parent class from child class?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

My home page has a toolbar with three buttons home,notification and login. I want notification button show only when user loged In. here is my code

```
//Parent class

@interface Toolbar : UIViewController {
UIToolbar *toolBar;
UIButton *home;
UIButton *notification;
    UIButton *login;
BOOL signIn;

}

@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL signIn;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *home;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *notification;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIButton *login;
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIToolbar *toolBar;


-(IBAction)Home:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)LogIn:(id)sender;
```

//Toolbar.m

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];


if (!signIn) {
    [notification setHidden:YES];
    [login setHidden:NO];
}else {
    [notification setHidden:NO];
    [login setHidden:YES];
}
```

}

//Child class

@interface LoginScreen : Toolbar{

LoginScreen.m

```
-(IBAction)SignIn{
if ([emailField.text isEqualToString:@"m"] && [passwordField.text isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
    NSLog(@"loggedIN");
    signIn=YES;

    Home *home=[[Home alloc]initWithNibName:@"Home" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];
    [home release];
}else {
//other condition
}
```

}

problem is I am able to to go back to home but signIn condition is not working. please guide me . Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Protocol`s (delegate mechanism) to send back the value to the parent view controller.

See [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) for some sample. Also [here](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/delegates/how-to-create-a-delegate)

You can find many samples for this in every Apple sample application.

I have also give you a [Sample Application](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/). Go through that and modify the protocol as per your need

Comment: I have used the protocol defined in below question .. but no help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368757/setting-property-value-of-parent-viewcontroller-class-from-child-viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.... but in all examples both class inherit uiviewcontroller class but in my case i am inheriting one of my class into another and this gave me error..

Comment: Is it possible for you to send the 2 classes?

Comment: May we know the reason why you have made the `LoginScreen` as subclass of `Toolbar`?