# How can I pass the value from UITextField to UITableViewCell iOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to display the text entered in the textfield to the table view cell of the same view controller but in different views in iPhone. (i.e) table view is in one view and textfield is in another view when i enter the text and click ok button below the textfield, the value to be get passed to the UITableViewCell.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: provide your code that you have tried

Comment: @SunilPandey thanks for ur instant response. i am very new to iPhone development, here what i indent to do is, i have a view controller in that, i include UIbutton and uitableview in the same controller. Below the UITableView i have four buttons @ the bottom. Clicking on one button will load a new view, that includes UITextfield and a button. If i enter a text into the textfield and click button, then the text from that view to be get display in the UITableview row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate to send the data back to the parent view controller.

For more detail, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075024/how-to-pass-value-to-a-variable-defined-in-parent-class-from-child-class/9075102#9075102)

**Edit:**

[Sample App](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/)

Comment: thanx for ur reply. i am very new to the iPhone development. Can u send any delegate sample tutorial for me pls!

Comment: Did you check the link in my answer? Anyhow, I have reposted it again.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..Ya i go through what u have posted here, What i indent to do is, i have a view controller in that, i include UIbutton and uitableview in the same. Below the UITableView i have four buttons @ the bottom. Clicking on one button will load a new view not another controller it's only UIView, that includes UITextfield and a button. If i enter a text into the textfield and click  OK button, then the text from that view to be get display in the UITableview row.. Pls be Patient with me.. i am very new to this..